# Intel Ultimate-N Desktop Antennas

Tags: wireless-networking

I'll be installing an Intel Ultimate-N 6300 in a desktop computer.  What I'm unsure about is which antennas to buy.
I want to have the normal "Black Pole" type desktop antenna I typically see for the add-on wireless desktop cards, instead of the thin square type of laptop aerial's.
So, do I just purchase three of the same kind of antenna? As long as the physical connector works?
The research I have done is the intel 6300 card uses 3-U.FL coax connectors, 2.4 GHz antennas?
Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just buy a different wireless adaptor going to be tough to replace the antennas for the device.

Comment: I've decided on the ultimate-N...the Killer-N 1103 also has 450 mbs specs, but it too has 3 antennas connections. Changing antennas is simple...it is just a typical SMA screw on connection.  I just dont know if the black pole type antennas are for both 2.4GHz and 5.0GHz, or do I get separate 2.4GHz and 5.0GHz

Comment: The "black pole type antennas" are just a metal antenna with a plasic case.